# How to get the number of hits in a web service by a user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net mvc4 web api. to prevent the unwanted and more than usual number of hits in a perticular time, I want to keep track of total number of hits by a user in perticular time. if number of hits exceeds the threshold value, the user will be given a warning message.
Is it possibe to do this for web api without using session?

please describe which methods are used to implement this. I am totally new guy in this field.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use session?

Comment: Usually you can use an ActionFilter (not the MVC action filter but ActionFilterAttribute from the System.Web.HttpFilters), you should be able to track. I can't give a definite answer because I don't know why you don't want to use the session. You want to use the threashold per user right?

Comment: I am using REST api. that's why no session. and yes threshold per user

Comment: I am trying to manage session by cookies. please help in this context

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about one of the important aspects of having an API: identity and monitoring. There are many ways to tackle the issue but if you are building an API for public consumption you have to build a system just to do that.

An API Key is a popular form of identification. And you normally will build an authorization system to control access. There is nothing in the framework itself to do this for you.

As I have explained this more in this [post](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/api-layer-and-its-responsibilities-rest-viewpoint-webapi-csds-aspnetwebapi.html).

Comment: Can you please provide any way to implement this.